# UIView Subclass fixed height on initialization

Tags: swift, uiview, autolayout, initialization, subclass

I have a UIButton subclass that needs to be 80pt in height but have width behave normally when used in UIStackView etc... How can this be accomplished in the subclass.

The below code successfully changes the height, but the UIStackView does not adjust the layout to accurate the height:

```
class MenuSelectionButton: UIButton {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        var newFrame = frame
        newFrame.size.height = 80
        frame = newFrame
    }

}
```

**Working Code:**

```
class MenuSelectionButton: UIButton {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        addHeightConstraint()
    }

    private func addHeightConstraint () {
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 80)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([heightConstraint])
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constrain the button's height to 80 and let auto layout handle it.

Alternatively, since you're using a custom subclass of `UIButton`, override `instrinsicContentSize` to return a height of 80:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class MenuSelectionButton: UIButton {

    // Xcode uses this to render the button in the storyboard.
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    // The storyboard loader uses this at runtime.
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: super.intrinsicContentSize().width, height: 80)
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    }

}
```

Comment: This would need to be done within the button subclass to avoid the need to add the constraint in every instance of the button manually - is that possible?

Comment: I assumed, from the fact that you defined `init(coder:)`, that you're loading the button from a storyboard. You can create the constraint in the storyboard.

Comment: There is no accompanying XIB file for the button - it is a straight subclass of UIButton. The buttons are being added to other XIB files, and it is possible to add the constraints there, but it was much easier to add the constraint programmatically as shown in my edit question.

Comment: I've updated my answer with another solution that you might like better.